# Problem with solving integral - $\int_a^{b}w^2\phi(w)dw$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, normal-distribution, self-learning

What rule has been applied here:

$\int_a^{b}w^2\phi(w)dw=\int_a^{b}w\phi(w)d\frac{w^2}{2}$

where $\phi(w)$ is a PDF of standard normal distribution. I am confused with $d\frac{w^2}{2}$ and how to solve this further.

Please note that this is a excerpt from calculating variance of truncated normal distribution which can be found at http://dongguo.me/me/blog/2013/12/02/gaussian-and-truncated-gaussian/ .

Comment: It's a way of proceeding with integration by parts

Comment: @Test123 I would be very thankful if you could provide a link with similar (perhaps simpler) solved example.

Comment: Check this: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegrationbyParts.html

Comment: @Test123 I still cannot see how to integrate this to get the final result.